# Different IP - Ubuntu Server on Win10 (Oracle VM)

Tags: virtualization, ip

Iam running Ubunutu Server in Oracle VM on Win 10.

I checked ifconfig and my inet adress is 10.2.X.XX for eth0

On my Windows Pc is my Ip is 91.51.XXX.XXX

Shouldnt both IPs be the same?

And how to connect to my ubuntu server from outside?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about **Oracle VirtualBox** ?

You are likely running the VM in `NAT` networking mode. `NAT`, short for `Network Address Translation` will mean that any traffic going out to the network from the VM will appear as if it is coming from your host device. In your case, it would appear as if it is coming from `91.51.XXX.XXX`. Outside hosts will only be able to talk back to your host (e.g., respond to web requests) if the conversation originated (was established and tagged with `NAT headers`) in your VM.

You can read more about VirtualBox and `NAT` [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat)

I won't delve too deep into the technicalities, but a quick fix for you should be to simply change the network adapter for your VM to run in `Bridged` mode.

To do this:

- Open **Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager**.
- `right-click` your VM and click `Settings`
- Click on the `Network` menu item on the left.
- Assuming you have only 1 adapter, change the `Attached To` setting to `Bridged Adapter`
- (Optional) By default, your hosts machine's ethernet adapter will be selected as the bridged adapter. You can change this to any other device, e.g. wireless, by choosing your preferred bridge interface in the dropdown menu next to `Name`

Then, you can go into your Ubuntu Server (the guest VM) and do the following:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sleep 1 && sudo ifup eth0
```

This should refresh your IP to be assigned by a DHCP server on your main network and you should be able to reach the server from outside.

Alternatively, you can configure [port forwarding](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward).